# Background Processing in android using Intent service

Tags: android, sqlite, intentservice

I am trying to do Background Processing in android using Intent-service, In my project user can able to store a number of records in SQLite(when a user at offline mode), Whenever user connected WiFi or mobile data user trying to sync offline data and simultaneously he is entering new data in SQLite.

When user enter new records while sync the data device performance is very slow and UI also freezing, Anything wrong in my way of process can someone help me, please

### code:-

```
public class NetworkIntentServiceForOfflineDetails extends IntentService {

    // IntentService can perform, e.g. ACTION_FETCH_NEW_ITEMS
    private static final String ACTION = ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION;
    //private NetworkChangeReceiver networkChangeReceiver;
    public NetworkIntentServiceForOfflineDetails() {
        super("NetworkIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {

            DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = new DatabaseAccess(this);
            databaseAccess.open();
            List<OfflineDataObj> offlineInfo = databaseAccess.getDetailsInfo();
            databaseAccess.close();
            UserPreferences.setPreferenceBoolean(Constants.IS_ALARM_ON, false);
            if (offlineInfo.size() == 0) {
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (NetWorkConnection.isConnected()) {

                try {
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < offlineInfo.size(); i++) {

                            OfflineDataObj offlineDataObj = offlineInfo.get(i);
                            String userId = UserPreferences.getPreferenceString(Constants.USER_ID,
                                    null);
                            String url = ServerUrls.SUBMIT_PROJECT_DETAILS_TO_SERVER + userId + "/" + "project_submissions";

VolleyHelperPostForOffline().callVolleyHelperPost(url, offlineDataObj.getJson(),
                                  Constants.NOTIFICATION_SUBMIT_PROJECT_DETAILS_TO_SERVER, this, null,
                                    offlineDataObj);

                    }
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                setAlarm();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void setAlarm() {
        UserPreferences.setPreferenceBoolean(Constants.IS_ALARM_ON, true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(NetworkIntentServiceForOfflineDetails.this, NetworkIntentServiceForOfflineDetails.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(NetworkIntentServiceForOfflineDetails.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + Constants.ALARM_TIME_FOR_OFFLINEDATA, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there no one for suggest me

Comment: you should move databaseAccess.open(); to oncreate and databaseAccess.close(); to ondestry

Comment: What do you mean?,Is this solve my problem?